# Find Task names of an SSIS file or Find xml code of an ssis package from sql server 2019 using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2019

there is a Windows Server which runs an SQL Server 2019 instance at my company. I have deployed an Integration services solution (project deployment model) with some SSIS packages. I wondered if there is any way to get data flow task names from the packages, or to get the xml file body in order to extract names by using T-SQL. If none of the above is possible i would like to know in which directory the actual dtsx files are stored in Windows Server when you deploy a solution in SQL Server. I have searched a lot for the above but i cannot find any answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the package deployed? If it's File System, you could likely do something like Powershell and SQL. I can't, personally, remember if packages deployed in msdb are encrypted (I haven't used the deployment method since 2012), however, if they are deployed via SSISDB you won't be able to query the packages stored in the database as they are all encrypted. You'd need to inspect the source packages (in your source controlled project).

Comment: Hello, packages are deployed in SQL server using Project deployment model from Visual Studio 2019, i cannot locate them in msdb tables, i only can find them by quering: SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.packages. @Larnu thanks for your answer.

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67886074/find-task-names-of-an-ssis-file-or-find-xml-code-of-an-ssis-package-from-sql-ser#comment119990521_67886074) above: *"if they are deployed via SSISDB you won't be able to query the packages stored in the database as they are all encrypted. You'd need to inspect the source packages (in your source controlled project). "*

Comment: @Larnu i noticed your comment. Thanks a lot for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is the package deployed? If it's File System, you could likely do
> something like Powershell and SQL. I can't, personally, remember if
> packages deployed in msdb are encrypted (I haven't used the deployment
> method since 2012), however, if they are deployed via SSISDB you won't
> be able to query the packages stored in the database as they are all
> encrypted. You'd need to inspect the source packages (in your source
> controlled project).

From [a comment by @Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67886074/find-task-names-of-an-ssis-file-or-find-xml-code-of-an-ssis-package-from-sql-ser/68833891#comment119990521_67886074)